# Laptop freezes in High Performance mode and plugged in to charger

Tags: freeze, touchpad, charging

I own an ASUS N46V and it keeps freezing when plugged in and set to Power4Gear Entertainment mode. Power4Gear mode causes no problems if the laptop is running on battery power.

And I see that it also affects the touchpad; I usually turn it off because I'm using a mouse but now every time I turn the laptop on, it is turned on and I can't set it off with a shortcut - I have to go to Control Panel and choose "Mouse" and click on "Apply" to set it off and make the shortcut works. I think this is somehow related, since this also started when my laptop froze the first time.

Any help? Currently I'm using Power4Gear Battery Saving mode to prevent the freezing (touchpad issue still there). It would be great to not having to re-install my windows or to send this to the service center (too much data - nowhere to back-up and have a deadline coming up).

Comment: Just to clarify, it freezes _both_ when you simply plug it in _and_ when you set it to high performance mode? Or does it freeze only when _simultaneously_ plugged in and in HP mode?

Comment: both when plugged in and HP mode. HP mode in Battery is fine.